# Android Mockito-Kotlin error - "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-testing, mockito-kotlin

The following is the test code for my `ViewModel` class. My app architecture is based on MVI. Basically, I'm trying to mock my repo and state classes. In the test function I wrote below, I'm trying to check if state is changed in correct order when I successfully load a news list from an API.

```
class NewsListViewModelTest {
    //...

    @get:Rule
    val testSchedulerRule = RxTestSchedulerRule()

    private lateinit var testSubject: NewsListViewModel    

    private val loadingState = NewsListState(state = State.LOADING)

    private val newsRepo = mock<NewsRepository>()
    private val observer = mock<Observer<NewsListState>>()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        testSubject = NewsListViewModel(newsRepo)
        testSubject.observableState.observeForever(observer)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Given news list successfully loaded, when action LoadNewsList is received, then state contains news list`() {
        // GIVEN
        val newsList = listOf(News("title", "description", Date(), "image"))
        val successState = NewsListState(newsList = newsList, state = State.DATA)

        whenever(newsRepo.loadAll("keyword", 1, 1))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(newsList))

        // WHEN
        testSubject.dispatch(NewsListAction.LoadNewsList("keyword"))
        testSchedulerRule.triggerActions()

        // THEN
        inOrder(observer) {
            verify(observer).onChanged(loadingState)
            verify(observer).onChanged(successState)
        }
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(observer)
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test, I'm getting the following error in the first line inside `inOrder(observer){ ... }`:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
observer.onChanged(
    NewsListState(newsList=[], state=LOADING, errorMessage=)
);
-> at [packagename].NewsListViewModelTest.Given news list failed to load, when action LoadNewsList is received, then state contains error(NewsListViewModelTest.kt:77)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

And these are my testing dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
```

What might be the reason of this error?

**Edit** -- My `RxTestSchedulerRule` class:

```
class RxTestSchedulerRule(private val testScheduler: TestScheduler = TestScheduler()) : Scheduler(),
    TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description?): Statement {
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        return base
    }

    override fun createWorker() = testScheduler.createWorker()

    fun triggerActions() = testScheduler.triggerActions()
}
```

**Edit 2** -- My dispatch function:

```
fun dispatch(?) {
     newsRepository.loadAll(keyword = it.keyword, 
                            pageSize = pageSize, 
                            page = page)
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
                   .map<NewsListChange> { newsList -> 
                         NewsListChange.Data(newsList) } 
                  .defaultIfEmpty(NewsListChange.Data(emptyList())) 
                  .onErrorReturn { throwable -> 
                       NewsListChange.Error(throwable) } 
                  .startWith(NewsListChange.Loading)
}
```

Comment: You need to debug the code line-by-line using your IDE debugger and see why the observer is not called.

Comment: @Wojtek I debugged the code. The code run didn't continue after the following line: `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. I also added my test scheduler rule class above.

Comment: can you show your dispatch method ?

Comment: it looks like you are sending 3 parameters in the mock, yet only 1 parameter in the invocation of the mock, can you please correct the parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try instead of this line

```
whenever(newsRepo.loadAll("keyword", 1, 1))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(newsList))
```

put

```
whenever(newsRepo.loadAll(anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt()))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(newsList))
```